# Phone keeps making multiple copies of my pictures when Syncing with Windows 8

Tags: 8.0, sync, pictures, windows-8

Every time I connect my WP8 with a windows 8 machine it makes 10+ copies of all my images,
has anyone else seen this problem?  Is there a setting in the Phone Sync, do I have a bad App, haven't heard of anyone else having this problem, and can't find any help online.

Comment: using the Win RT(Metro) App, looking into it a little more, I plugged it into a win7 box and looked at the files and it's not actually coping the files multiple times, it's just showing the same picture multiple times in the phone gallery and the win RT sync app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this,

1. Mark and Delete all pictures from phone itself (Don't delete from PC client). It may show a message that some pictures can't delete. Ignore it.
2. Then start sync with PC.
3. Actually this is caused because of multiple thumbnail/shortcut for a same image. It will not consume your space not much. But still irritating.

Comment: I ended up backing up the images then deleting them all, looks like win 8 sync tool had a bug, after it upgraded haven't had any problems