# Why there are multiple copies of Photos in Saved Picture in my Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, photos

There are 5 copies of each photo which are saved in my "Saved Pictures" albulm. Why does this happen ? What is the way to stop this from happening ?

Comment: Well, depends who saved them. If you used an app it could save as many photos as it wants if you gave permission. If you go to a web site and hold tap in a picture and after that save how many pictures does it saves?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. They are not copies, it's one file and more than one thumbnails/ shortcuts. I'm still looking for the solutions.

Comment: @NK are these photos happened to be from one app? like WhatsApp or Wee Chat?

Comment: Nop, any new picture we saved in phone will be replicated. And the good news is that issue is fixed for me without doing anything. (But I did soft reset and and something something for some other issues)

Comment: I have the same issue. Photos saved from any apps (including IE, whatsapp and wechat) seems to duplicate themselves, and get worse overtime. Originally I have 3 duplicates when I first noticed the issue, then it has grew to 5, and 7. I do have the auto-upload to skydrive option enabled.
When I check the files on skyDrive they are not duplicated. My guess is that perhaps after the auto-upload, the photos app is "confused" and shows multiple copies (or even downloading it back as duplicates). I did a soft reset today and the issue is fixed.
I will need to monitor the issue to see if it arise aga

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone keeps making multiple copies of my pictures when Syncing with Windows 8](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/phone-keeps-making-multiple-copies-of-my-pictures-when-syncing-with-windows-8)

Comment: Are you using OneDrive or syncing the phone with your computer?